# Cloned ArrayList

Tags: arraylist

I am writing a small program for a data structures class that basically stores member objects. One of the things the user needs to be able to do is delete and add new users. That being said, I use an arraylist to hold my objects and then I clone it so that I can have two arraylists sorted in different ways. Changing object fields in one list DOES change them in the other but when I delete an object from one arraylist, it still stays in the other. What would be the best method to completely delete that member object from all arraylists?

Comment: What platform/language are you using? My guess is Java, but it's only a guess...

Comment: One way would be to add an isDeleted field to the object, and treat any record with that field set to true as deleted.  This gets messy, though, when you try to count items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way would be to write a helper method that would remove the element from each of the array lists, and use that method for the removal.